# Flexslider captions showing below not on top of image

Tags: jquery, css, slider, flexslider

I have seen this asked before on Stackoverflow but cant find an precise answer.  I just want the captions to overlay on my image.  Instead they seem to just fall below.  I am assuming this is probably a positioning issue, but can not find any other resource that will pinpoint the problem.  I figured I would ask here.  Thanks for your time in advance. 
Below is the CSS, HTML and JavaScript and jQuery.  I have followed the instructions as stated by Flexslider for installation.

CSS

```
    .flex-container a:active,
.flexslider a:active,
.flex-container a:focus,
.flexslider a:focus  {outline: none;}
.slides,
.flex-control-nav,
.flex-direction-nav {margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none;} 

/* FlexSlider Necessary Styles
*********************************/ 
.flexslider {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
.flexslider .slides > li {display: none; -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;} /* Hide the slides before the JS is loaded. Avoids image jumping */
.flexslider .slides img {width: 100%; display: block;}
.flex-pauseplay span {text-transform: capitalize;}

/* Clearfix for the .slides element */
.slides:after {content: "."; display: block; clear: both; visibility: hidden; line-height: 0; height: 0;} 
html[xmlns] .slides {display: block;} 
* html .slides {height: 1%;}

/* No JavaScript Fallback */
/* If you are not using another script, such as Modernizr, make sure you
 * include js that eliminates this class on page load */
.no-js .slides > li:first-child {display: block;}


/* FlexSlider Default Theme
*********************************/
.flexslider {margin: 0 0 60px; background: #fff; border: 4px solid #fff; position: relative; -webkit-border-radius: 4px; -moz-border-radius: 4px; -o-border-radius: 4px; border-radius: 4px; box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2); -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2); -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2); -o-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2); zoom: 1;}
.flex-viewport {max-height: 2000px; -webkit-transition: all 1s ease; -moz-transition: all 1s ease; transition: all 1s ease;}
.loading .flex-viewport {max-height: 300px;}
.flexslider .slides {zoom: 1;}

.carousel li {margin-right: 5px}


/* Direction Nav */
.flex-direction-nav {*height: 0;}
.flex-direction-nav a {width: 30px; height: 30px; margin: -20px 0 0; display: block; background: url(images/bg_direction_nav.png) no-repeat 0 0; position: absolute; top: 50%; z-index: 10; cursor: pointer; text-indent: -9999px; opacity: 0; -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;}
.flex-direction-nav .flex-next {background-position: 100% 0; right: -36px; }
.flex-direction-nav .flex-prev {left: -36px;}
.flexslider:hover .flex-next {opacity: 0.8; right: 5px;}
.flexslider:hover .flex-prev {opacity: 0.8; left: 5px;}
.flexslider:hover .flex-next:hover, .flexslider:hover .flex-prev:hover {opacity: 1;}
.flex-direction-nav .flex-disabled {opacity: .3!important; filter:alpha(opacity=30); cursor: default;}

/* Control Nav */
.flex-control-nav {width: 100%; position: absolute; bottom: -40px; text-align: center;}
.flex-control-nav li {margin: 0 6px; display: inline-block; zoom: 1; *display: inline;}
.flex-control-paging li a {width: 11px; height: 11px; display: block; background: #666; background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); cursor: pointer; text-indent: -9999px; -webkit-border-radius: 20px; -moz-border-radius: 20px; -o-border-radius: 20px; border-radius: 20px; box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);}
.flex-control-paging li a:hover { background: #333; background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7); }
.flex-control-paging li a.flex-active { background: #000; background: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); cursor: default; }

.flex-control-thumbs {margin: 5px 0 0; position: static; overflow: hidden;}
.flex-control-thumbs li {width: 25%; float: left; margin: 0;}
.flex-control-thumbs img {width: 100%; display: block; opacity: .7; cursor: pointer;}
.flex-control-thumbs img:hover {opacity: 1;}
.flex-control-thumbs .flex-active {opacity: 1; cursor: default;}

@media screen and (max-width: 860px) {
  .flex-direction-nav .flex-prev {opacity: 1; left: 0;}
  .flex-direction-nav .flex-next {opacity: 1; right: 0;}
}
```

JQuery and Javascript

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/flexslider.css" type="text/css">
        <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.flexslider.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(window).load(function() {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
          animation: "slide",
          controlsContainer: ".flex-container"
    });
  });
```

HTML

```
    <div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flexslider">
    <ul class="slides">
      <li>
        <img src="img/Kemper_Mark.jpg" />
        <p class="flex-caption">Captions and cupcakes. Winning combination.</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="img/octoberfest.jpg" />
        <p class="flex-caption">This image is wrapped in a link!</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="img/plat_club.jpg".jpg" />
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 29):

It seems that u haven't added flex-caption css

```
.flexslider .slides li {
    position:relative;
}

.flex-caption {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    background:#000; /* whatever you want */    
    z-index:1;
    padding:5px;
}
```

try this maybe it will work...
let me know if it works

Comment: For me position:relative did the trick. I had the .flex-caption class already but positioning wasn't right.  position:relative on .flexslider .slides li fixed it

Answer (score 2):

dipak's answer above worked great. Mine ended up being

```
.flex-caption {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50;
    right: 50;
    bottom: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0,0.6);
    z-index: 1;
    padding: 10px;
 }
```

which gives the caption a black background with opacity of .6

I just added this to the  bottom of the flexslider.css

Answer (score 0):

Relocated the pager(nav controls) to the right with left:45%

```
.flex-control-nav {
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  left: 45%;
  /* bottom:7.3%; */
  text-align:center;
}
```